# How to get the largest value from a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

What is the syntax to get the maximum character length from a column in a table. For example if I have something like this:

```
id | name | occupation
----------------------
1  | John  | writer
2  | Lisa  | waitress
3  | Timmy | soldier
```

And I wanted to get the largest value from the name column it would return:

```
3  | Timmy | soldier
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are more rows having the same maximum length you'll find them with

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(column) = ( SELECT MAX(LENGTH(column)) FROM table )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function as a sort criteria with a `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` ORDER BY LENGTH(`name`) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Bear in mind, `LENGTH()` is based on the length of the string in bytes. Use `CHAR_LENGTH()` if you want the length based on the number of characters.

Comment: If there is more than one row with the same maximum length you won't show them all.